# How to import images in new form

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am new in JavaFX, this is my code. This application has a button, If you click on the button opens new form. Does anyone know how to insert a picture into a new form?

```
package javafxwindow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Packages that I used.
The class JavaFXWindow.

```
public class JavaFXWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Open a New Window");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            Label secondLabel = new Label("Hello");

            StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
            secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);

            Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 200, 100);

            Stage secondStage = new Stage();
            secondStage.setTitle("New Stage");
            secondStage.setScene(secondScene);

            secondStage.show();

        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> Platform.exit());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a child ImageView to secondaryLayout. For example;

```
ImageView imageViewTest = new ImageView(new Image("com/test/images/test.png"));
secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(imageViewTest);
```

But you need to write correct path for test.png. It would be written after your src package.

Comment: How to add 4 images in new form? Thanks.

Comment: "path" is misleading. It should be a ***URL***! @somiludak how about trying something yourself. Warning: You may get some experience doing this...